# QDomElement: set boolean attribute

Tags: xml, qt

Is there a reason why QDomElement has not this function:

```
void setAttribute(const QString & name, bool value);
```

what I have to do in my code is somthing like:

```
element.setAttribute("boolean_attribute", this->booleanValue() ? "true" : "false");
```

Horrible, but I can't see alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [boolean data type](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_misc.asp) for xml, this states: -

> *Note: Legal values for boolean are true, false, 1 (which indicates true), and 0 (which indicates false).*

If setting the value to true, false and 1 all indicate true, it can be misleading. I expect it's for this reason that your proposed function does not exist, so that one must implicitly handle the value here.

Comment: +1 I edited my answer and added my point of view, but your answer is good. Let the OP decide.

Comment: "true, false and 1 all indicate true" ? From what you wrote seems that true and 1 indicate true. Qt could choose for example to write "true"/"false" like in my example and read and parse all possible values: "true", "false", "1", "0". Is not it?

Comment: If the function argument accepted a string, what would it do if you pass in something other than "true", "false", "1" or "0"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `0` and `1` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`. For example:

```
        if(e.attribute("value").toInt())
            qDebug() << "it is true";
        else
            qDebug() << "it is false";
```

gives correct result with lines:

`<Attribute value="0"/>`  or `<Attribute value="1"/>`

I think it is better than compare strings. And `setAttribute` supports `int`.

Edit:

`attribute()` returns `QString` and `QString` has no method `toBool` or something like that, so it has no sense to provide method which supports writing `bool` if we can't read it correctly in future.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, does it?!

Comment: @Merlin069 Unfortunately I don't understand. Do you think that using int instead of strings is bad or you means that I didn't answer why  QDomElement has not this function with bool ?

Comment: I mean it didn't answer the question as to why the function does not exist, so it's more of a comment than an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: @Merlin069 I searched something about bool in xml in the web. Someone use tags with 0 and 1, we talking about attribute, someone use "yes" or "true" and one more. My assumption: `QDomElement::attribute` returns `QString`, but QString has not method toBool, so how we should get bool? Maybe it is not best explanation but it seems that Qt just don't support this